# Добавить в справку информацию про блокировку комментариев

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, заблокированные-сообщения

Появилась возможность [блокировать только комментарии](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340198/260198).

Нужно в [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) добавить информацию об этом. В [eng справке](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts) добавлен текст:

> The one exception to this is the "Comments only lock", which only prevents new comments from being added to the question or answer that is locked.

Comment: Надо бы ещё как-то определиться в каких ситуациях этот инструмент применять и описать это.

Comment: @AK описать в справке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз уж @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica не хочет править свой ответ, предложу немного исправленную версию отдельно:

> Единственным исключением является "блокировка только комментариев", не позволяющая лишь добавлять новые комментарии к заблокированному вопросу или ответу, но при этом оставляющая возможность голосовать, редактировать, использовать тревоги на сообщении и т. п.

Здесь слово *`оставляя`* заменено на *`оставляющая`.*

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю вариант:

> Единственным исключением является "блокировка только комментариев", не позволяющая лишь добавлять новые комментарии к заблокированному вопросу или ответу, но при этом оставляя возможность голосовать, редактировать, использовать тревоги на сообщении и т.п.

Comment: Не надо "only" выкидывать, оно там важно.

Comment: @Qwertiy так вроде и не выкидывал. В моём вариант есть "только" о_О

Comment: Я про "which only prevents".

Comment: @Qwertiy поправил.

Comment: _"оставляя"_ - вроде должно быть "оставляющая"?

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде как и так, и так можно.